# How to add Hyperlink in a New Window with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to insert target="_blank" into this PHP code below so I can click on the icon fa fa-search and open the link in a new window, could anyone help me with the right syntax?

```
    // actions
$actions = "";
if ($product['mp.product_status'] != MsProduct::STATUS_DISABLED) {
    if ($product['mp.product_status'] == MsProduct::STATUS_ACTIVE)
        $actions .= "<a class='icon-view' href='" . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL') ."' title='" . $this->language->get('ms_viewinstore') . "'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>";
```

Comment: What was the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: `<a target="_blank" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added the target="_blank" just before href att.

```
$actions .= "<a class='icon-view' target='_blank' href='" . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL') ."' title='" . $this->language->get('ms_viewinstore') . "'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>";
```